# Chi-square test approach for RNG evaluation

Tags: random, chi-squared

I am in RNG evaluation testing, RNG used in online gambling. Earlier I haven't use Chi-square testing for the same. But now most of the clients are demanding to use it. I understood the test very well. But I am concern about getting the actual count of particular symbols from scaled data? How can we calculate the same from scaled data? OR can we used simulation of games?

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests). And I strongly urge you to seek testing from an independent testing lab like TST or GLI.

Comment: Well, those are my competitors! I am into Compliance testing!